# Filtering Dataset in Spark with String Search

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to just do a simple string filter with the dataset api using `startsWith` but I can't get the below statement to work. I can use `contains` like this. Not sure what I'm missing here.

```
  ds.filter(_.colToFilter.toString.contains("0")).show(false)
```

But this just produces an empty dataset but I know that the string is there in the value.

```
  ds.filter(_.colToFilter.toString.startsWith("0")).show(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subString` *inbuilt function* as

## Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.filter(substring(col("column_name-to-be_used"), 0, 1) === "0")
```

## Pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.filter(f.substring(f.col("column_name-to-be_used"), 0, 1) == "0")
```

So you can *substring to as many characters you want to check in starts-with*

Comment: thank you but was looking for a type safe way using dataset api. My problem turned out to be that my datatype was using an Option and therefore was not returning anything. I just removed the Option for now.

Comment: That alright. I was just trying to solve the issue you had presented in the question ;). If the answer helped you then you can upvote and accept it

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
val d = ds.filter($"columnToFilter".contains("0"))
```

or

```
val d = ds.filter($"columnToFilter".startsWith("0"))
```

**Example**

```
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

Assume we have the above `dataset`, the output will be:

```
> var d = ds.filter($"name".contains("n"))

+---+------+
|age|  name|
+---+------+
| 30|  Andy|
| 19|Justin|
+---+------+

> var d = ds.filter($"name".startsWith("A"))

+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 30|Andy|
+---+----+
```